# Jquery Ajax method POST does not work on remote server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I've been working on a website for quite some time, but it was all done on localhost. After making login form work properly I decided to upload it to hosting.
Issue is that callback functions of ajax don't seem to work if I use method: `POST`
If I change `POST` to `GET` it will work...

Ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
      method: 'POST',
      url: "php/login.php",
      data: { username: val_username, password: val_password },
      success: function(response) {
        if (response == 0) {
          location.reload();
        } else {
          alert("Wrong username or password. Error #"+response);
        }
      }
    });
```

login.php

```
<?php

session_start();

require "../php_includes/mysql.php";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($db_server, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// escape your parameters to prevent sql injection
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['username']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM korisnici WHERE username='$username'";
$sql_result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($sql_result->num_rows > 0) {
    $row = $sql_result->fetch_assoc();
    if (password_verify($password, $row["password"])) {
        $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
        $_SESSION["userid"] = $row["id"];
        echo 0;
    } else echo 2;
} else echo 1;

?>
```

I have checked all the file locations, no issue there, since everything works if I change method to GET.

I tried changing datatypes in ajax, tried adding some headers to php file that I've found searching around stackoverflow, but nothing helps...

Comment: What's actually being sent in the request? And what do you mean *it doesn't work*?

Comment: It's sending pure text: username and password that user has entered into html form.

Comment: Is the `success` callback being triggered on POST? If not, try to set an `error`-callback and check what it says.

Comment: It's sending pure text? What are you expecting it to send?

Comment: Okay, let it send pure or impure text. What it returns when it is `POST` and what it returns when it is `GET`?

Comment: Inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network for clues. What is status? Is url as expected?...what is sent ?, what is returned? etc Also trim response in case getting extra whitespace

Comment: @Aneszej - Then please tell us what it says. "Not workind" doesn't give us much to go on.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Success callback isn't being triggered, error on the other hand is.  
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {  
            alert(textStatus);  
            alert(errorThrown);  
          }  
this returns following:  
alert1: "Error"  
alert2: "Internal server error"  
And Im expecting it to send that text to php, to validate data, and if it's correct, to mark users session as logged in.

Comment: @Aneszej you can see everything in the request itself in network tab...go there are save lots of time. None of the information you just posted tells much. Inspect it closely!

Comment: Just a thought, what PHP-version is running on the hosting server?

Comment: You have a php problem anyway from the `internal server error` message. Check server logs and turn on all error handling in php

Comment: I'm using PHP 5.4.45. And error shows Call to undefined function password_verify() which explains everything, since I'd need PHP >= 5.5. Thanks everyone, can I somehow mark your answers as correct?
Edit: hosting is using* I don't really have control of it, I'll just switch hosting

Comment: @Aneszej - I added an answer you can mark as correct. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have the same version of PHP on the hosting server (at least PHP 5.5 since you're using `password_verify()` which is for >= PHP 5.5).